# PWA UNLOCK PUSH NOTIFICATIONS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I have one PWA with push notifications (FireBase) and everything works fine until the user allows to receive notifications, if the user locks the notifications and later wants to change this option, how can I with "JavaScript Code" to unlock the notifications?

Comment: I believe that task is 100% in the hands of the user. If they gave that as an option to developers, some might use it in a not so nice way.

Comment: Hi.... but there are users that not have idea how to do that